# How can I show in the same line logo and title in HTML without CSS?

Tags: html

I would like to show in the  section a logo, title, and navigation menus without using CSS, only HTML 5 if that is possible but I can't make it work.

```
<body>
    <header>
        <img src="logo.png" width="128" height="128">
        <h1 >text</h1>
    </header>
</body>
```

Comment: It won't work since img and h1 have display block by default. What's the point to not use CSS? To achieve this more easily you can use Flexbox

Comment: I thought it may be possible to avoid CSS but if it not possible then I suppose the easier way is to create the <style> tag in <meta>. Is it right? I am just starting to learn HTML

Comment: The right way is to make a separate file for CSS. Use <link href="css_path.css" />.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a table? But I don't see why you wouldn't want to use CSS?

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><img src="https://hips.hearstapps.com/hmg-prod.s3.amazonaws.com/images/dog-puppy-on-garden-royalty-free-image-1586966191.jpg?crop=1.00xw:0.669xh;0,0.190xh&resize=640:*" alt="logo thats really just a dog" width="128px" height=-"auto" /></td>
    <td><p>some text<p></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just using HTML5, you could place the `img` tag in the `h1` tag. See the result below. It could be further enhanced with CSS, but it's up to you if/when you want to do that.

```html
<header>
  <h1>
    <img src="logo.png" width="128" height="128">
    text
  </h1>
</header>
```

Comment: I like the idea, I just see that the text is not centered to the height of the image. Can it be also centered?

Comment: That can be done with CSS: [`vertical-align: middle`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align).

Answer (score -1):

It's safe and cool to use css. However, you can span the image and text on the same line simply by making use  of span tags instead of h1 tag.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).